# How to put special tags for each form element?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I have form with fields:

```
$this -> add(
        array(
            'name' => 'firstfield',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'id' => 'id_firstfield'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'firstfield'
            ),
        )
    );

$this -> add(
        array(
            'name' => 'secondfield',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'id' => 'id_secondfield'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'secondfield'
            ),
        )
    );
```

when I use:

```
echo $this->formCollection($form);
```

in my view, I get:

```
[...]
<label for="id_firstfield">first field</label>
<input name="firstfield" type="text" id="id_firstfield" value="">
<label for="id_secondfield">second field</label>
<input name="secondfield" type="text" id="id_secondfield" value="">
[...]
```

but I want to get:

```
[...]
<div id="divforfirstfield">
    <label for="id_firstfield">first field</label>
    <input name="firstfield" type="text" id="id_firstfield" value="">
</div>
<div id="divforsecondfield">
    <label for="id_secondfield">second field</label>
    <input name="secondfield" type="text" id="id_secondfield" value="">
</div>
[...]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `formCollection()` this is not possible. However you can do it like this:

```
<div id="firstid">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('firstfield')); ?>
</div>
<div id="secondid">
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('secondfield')); ?>
</div>
```

If you want to have the comfort of just one function call to render the form, you'll have to extend the `formCollection()` view helper with one of your own who do this.